# Raise powershell error and stop execution of script

Tags: powershell

I am working on making a ReST api call to the token server and grab the token. Then make another ReST api call by passing in the token and save the query response. I'm able to achieve when everything works as expected. But, if I were to run into errors I need to raise the powershell error and want the execution of the powershell script to stop at the point of failure. I need to save the api response on to a network share as the next steps. I noticed the execution to continue even if the ReST api call fails for some reason. I'm using a generic `try{}` `catch{}` block with some generic error message. I've been trying to raise the actual error that the powershell is throwing but does not work.

***PoSh:***

```
    try {
        $clientSecret = ''
        $clientId = ''
        $tenantId = ''
        # Construct URI
        $uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
        # Construct Body
        $body = @{
            client_id = $clientId
            client_secret = $clientSecret
            scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
            grant_type = 'client_credentials'
        }
        $Uri = 'https://apiserver.com/v1/data'
        # Get OAuth 2.0 Token
        $tokenRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
        # Access Token
        $token = ($tokenRequest.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
        $api = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        "Error" 
Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
Write-Host "ErrorMessage:" $_.ErrorDetails.Message
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking to change `"Error"` for `$_.Exception.Message` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I tried this and no luck `Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
Write-Host "ErrorMessage:" $_.ErrorDetails.Message`. Updated the original post as well.

Comment: Do you see the error if you do `$Error[0]` ? If so, you can inspect the object and it's properties from there

Answer (score 0):

> I need to raise the powershell error and want the execution of the powershell script to stop at the point of failure.

When a terminating error triggers the `catch` block of a [`try` / `catch`/ `finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally), execution *continues* by default.

To rethrow such an error as a *script*-terminating (fatal) error, simply use `throw` inside your `catch` block.

Alternatively, if you don't need to process the error before rethrowing it, place `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the top your scope, which will cause any error, including *non*-terminating ones, to become *script*-terminating (fatal) errors.